# What are the ways I can demonstrate to the PhD admission committee that I am a highly motivated applicant?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have a STEM background. After failing in the CS MSc program, I got enrolled in a graduate program in Education. I was originally heavily motivated to do a Ph.D. in CS. But, after failing in CS, now I want to go for a Ph.D. in Education.

What are the ways I can demonstrate to the Ph.D. admission committee that I am a highly motivated applicant?

Comment: Letters of recommendation help. What others say can have more weight than what you say yourself.

Comment: How have you shown that motivation? Saying "I am motivated" does nothing; showing it does.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, but they are asking how.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience You can't demonstrate anything you haven't done. Can't really answer the question of "what ways can I demonstrate" without knowing what they've done.

Comment: You're answering the wrong question. Everyone (who applies) is motivated. You need to show that you're motivated, *competent* and a good fit.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to show at all the fact *that* you are motivated. I hope you're not misunderstanding what the term "letter of motivation" means. On how to write a LoM, there are various questions on this site.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica, you got that right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm a computer science professor; I regularly evaluate applications for my department's graduate programs.)

**You are asking the wrong question.**  You don't want to show your motivation; you want to show your *research potential*.

It really really really Does Not Matter how much you *want* to do a PhD in computer science.  Sure, all else being equal, we prefer to admit students who are excited about joining the program, but at a fundamental level, we assume that if you *aren't* motivated, you wouldn't have applied.

What we do want to see is concrete evidence of your future potential for computer science research.  Make no mistake: **Your "statement of purpose" or "statement of motivation" is actually a *research* statement.**  What are your research interests?  What is your research experience?  What are your research goals?  What specific expertise can you apply to your research?  What open problems do you think are cool?  How do you want to attack them?  We are looking for both personal and technical detail, written in the idiomatic language of researchers.  (Even if you're not a researcher yet, even if you don't know what your specific research interests are yet, that's the voice you should strive for.)

We do not want to read about how inspired you were by your first smart phone, or who many programming languages you know, or how you've been programming since you were in the womb.  Yeah, yeah, we've all been programming since we were in the womb.  What have you actually *done*?  And what do you want to do that nobody else has ever done?

Part of that concrete evidence is your scholastic record: In short, grades.  Normally these only matter if they're low, but yours *are* low.  So in addition to the discussion of your research, your application also needs to address the elephant in the room: You need to give at least a brief explanation of what went wrong in your MSc program, and you need to provide **evidence** that the same issues won't arise again.

All of this evidence needs to be visible not only in your statement, but in your letters of recommendation as well.

I *strongly* recommend reading [Mor Harchol-Balter's advice on applying the graduate school in computer science](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eharchol/gradschooltalk.pdf), which is based on her experience at Berkeley, MIT, and CMU.  Her advice is also consistent with my experience at Illinois.

Comment: "if you aren't motivated, you wouldn't have applied" I'm skeptical.  People get PhDs because they want to avoid getting a job.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, what is wrong with avoiding getting a job? Why is it a matter to consider while evaluating a Ph.D.applicant? Kindly, explain.

Comment: @user366312 "what is wrong with avoiding getting a job?"  I did not say it was wrong, just that it happens.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Right, but if they're not motivated to join the PhD program, they're probably not going to be motivated to develop a compelling research statement, either.  On the other hand, if they put in the effort to write a good research statement, they might be more motivated to do research  than they realized.

Comment: @user366312 As a general rule, running away from things is less likely to work than running toward things.